# Datatable row.add().draw() only displays first letter

Tags: datatable

I'm having difficulty in display my data in `datatable`.
So at first I have a sample data in the `datatable` and then when a button is click it will `clear()` the `datatable` and this is where will I add the rows please see below code of lines.

```
myTable.clear();

for (var i = 0; i < data.response.length; i++) {
     console.log(data.response[i]['username']);
     myTable.row.add(data.response[i]['username']).draw();
}
```

When checking what's inside `data.response[i]['username']` it has the correct text but when added in `row.add()` it only displays the first letter. Thank you in advance for your help.

---Update---

So I tried to add random letters instead to see if its only in my array but not
I used this`myTable.row.add('asdqwe').draw();` it returns the first character as well.

Comment: Are you using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)? If so, you should use the tag `datatables` instead of the tag `datatable`.

Comment: When creating a row using [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()), you need to provide an _array_ of data (or an object or a node). If you only provide a _string_, then DataTables (i.e. JavaScript) will treat it as an _array_ of characters. So, `'asdqwe'` will be handled as `[ 'a', 's', 'd', 'q', 'w', 'e' ]`.  So, instead, provide an array with the same number of elements as there are columns.